# Azure Bicep and create runbooks

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I am struggling with the Azure documentation and I am not finding any relevant examples that can help me defining an Azure runbook based on Bicep.

The official documentation doesn't provide much information about the possible parameters

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/runbooks?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Here is what I did

```
param runbookName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param automationAccount object

@allowed([
  'Graph'
  'GraphPowerShell'
  'GraphPowerShellWorkflow'
  'PowerShell'
  'PowerShellWorkflow'
  'Python2'
  'Python3'
  'Script'
])
param runbookType string = 'PowerShell'

param logProgress bool = true
param logVerbose bool = true
param logActivityTrace int = 0

resource runbookABC 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks@2019-06-01' = {
  name: runbookName
  location: location
  parent: automationAccount
  properties: {
    description: 'Execute runbook ABC'
    draft: {
      draftContentLink: {
        contentHash: {
          algorithm: 'string' <<== 1) which values are allowed here?
          value: loadTextContent('./scripts/abc.ps1') <<== 2) is this correct?
        }
        uri: 'string' <<== 3) what should I put here
        version: 'v1.0'
      }
      inEdit: false
      outputTypes: [
        'varA' <<== 4) how the mapping is done here?
      ]
      parameters: {}
    }
    logActivityTrace: logActivityTrace
    logProgress: logProgress
    logVerbose: logVerbose
    runbookType: runbookType
  }
}
```

As shown in the code above, I am unsure about the inputs:

1. contentHash > algorithm
2. contentHash > value
3. draftContentLink > uri
4. outputTypes

Any advices?
Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to specify a value necessary for any parameter. The docs are more a schema description. Normally I try to find some quick start template to build on.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/runbooks?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#quickstart-templates

The uri should be the path of the script content.

Comment: thanks @JulianHüppauff for the comment, you have right, but I am unsure what are the required parameters, what parameters can be provided and which ones are useful for my use-case. Usually the MS documentation is good enough, this is the first case where I find some lack of documentation